# Escaping a dot in a field name in Zend Framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, escaping

I have a problem in writing a query with Zend 1.11.3. I'm not able to get a field whose name contains a dot. Since I cannot edit the table I tried escaping the name, with no success.

My code is the following:

```
<?php

class RoomsTable extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract {

    ...

    function getRecord($id)
    {
        $fields = array(
            'id' => 'id',
            ...
            'attrib.floor' => 'attrib.floor',
            ...
        ); 

        $Select = $this->select()
        ->from($this->_name, $fields)
        ->where('id = ?',$id);

        $list = $Select->query()->fetchAll();
    }
}
?>
```

When I call:

```
$rooms_table = new RoomsTable();
$first_room = $rooms_table->getRecord(1);
```

I get:

```
Zend_Db_Table_Select_Exception: Select query cannot join with another table
```

So, the `attrib.floor` field is interpreted as an attempt to get a field from a different table, while it is an actual field name from this table.

I tried with the following without success:

```
'attrib\.floor' => 'attrib\.floor',

'`attrib.floor`' => '`attrib.floor`',

'"attrib.floor"' => '"attrib.floor"',
```

Do somebody know how to escape the dot, so that Zend allows me to get that field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-953 in the comments:

> Identifiers that contain a dot (".") character are automatically split on the dot(s), and each piece quoted separately. Thus identifiers support the "schema"."table" or "table"."column" syntax.
>
> If you have a database design that has table names or column names containing a dot character, this should be a very uncommon case, and it is not recommended. But you can work around it by using Zend_Db_Expr and quote the identifier yourself.

http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.9/Zend_Db/Expr/Zend_Db_Expr.html

So in this case the right way to write the field would be:

```
'attrib.floor' => new Zend_Db_Expr('`attrib.floor`')
```

Comment: Do you have a code sample of how to use it in requiring the fields from a query?